# Kusto ingestion limit and command throttle because of capacity policy

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I use kusto ingest client **kustoClient.IngestFromDataReader** to ingest data. And it throws exception *An error occurred for source: 'DataReader'. Error: 'Failed to ingest: State='Throttled', Status='The control command was aborted due to throttling. Retrying after some backoff might succeed. CommandType: 'DataIngestPull', Capacity: 18, Origin: 'CapacityPolicy/Ingestion'.'*. I read the document here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/capacitypolicy#ingestion-capacity, and guess it may because that there are too many requests run concurrently and the cluster capacity is limited, am I right?

I am still a bit confused about the document. What does the final number (Minimum(ClusterMaximumConcurrentOperations, Number of nodes in cluster * Maximum(1, Core count per node * CoreUtilizationCoefficient))) mean? Does it means the total concurrent operations number? And specifically does one kusto ingest client or one kusto ingest command only have one concurrent operation or it is configurable?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Effectively the document means that ingest capacity (in terms of concurrent ingest operations) is 3/4 times the overall number of cores in the cluster, but not higher than 512.
You can view your cluster capacity and its utilization by running '.show cluster capacity' command.

If you do not want to handle the throttling by yourself, you should use the [KustoQueuedIngestClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-reference#interface-ikustoqueuedingestclient) class, and pass to it the ingestion service endpoint (https://ingest-..kusto.windows.net).
The ingestion service will take care of managing the load on your cluster.
See [Ingestion Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-ingest) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A quick question, do you know that does copy activity of Azure data factory handle the throttling as well? So that we don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Yes, ADF's copy activity uses the ingest client that hits the managed ingestion endpoint, that will not throttle.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!